# Priming pentaho bi server cache

Tags: pentaho

I need to priming cache to Pentaho BI Server. I'm using Pentaho Data Integration, mondrian and pentaho bi server. I want precache my dashboard, but i dont know how to make this. I try wget with spider option, but this dont make any change.

Comment: What dashboard? CTools or EE Dashboard?

Comment: Hi @Codek, it's Ctools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the CDA file in the user console and you'll be able to get a URL to get the CDA data. USe this url in a http get step in PDI to prime the cda cache.

OR to get the initial URLs just simply use firebug or similar to see what CDA urls are called when the dashboard loads and then call these urls from PDI.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried 'Scheduled Queries' in the CDA Cache Manager from the Pentaho BI Server?

It works for me (Pentaho 7) but I'm not using PDI.

You can have a look to this post:

https://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?208467-CDA-Cache&p=439893#post439893

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes